# Regular expression of particular word in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to compare string like

- `"XYZ"`
- `" XYZ"`
- `"XYZ "`
- `",XYZ"`
- `", XYZ"`
- `"XYZ,"`
- `" XYZ ,"`
- `",XYZ,"`
- `", XYZ ,"`

Is any one have suggestion how to make regular expression of this particular string item?

Comment: do you want to include the double quotes in the comparision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
[,\s]*?XYZ[,\s]*
```

Comment: Yes, this works for all the cases you mentioned in your question. Did you give it a try?

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer, It is working fine. @Pradeep Kumar

Comment: One more case i want to share, If I enter this string "test XYZA test", In this senario its not working. can you give me the solution.?

Comment: If you want to match the whole line that contains this expression then this would work: `^.*[,\s]*?XYZ[,\s]*.*$`

Comment: I checked with your suggestion, but it not working with "test XYZA test".Dim strPattern As String = "(^.*[,\s]*?XYZ[,\s]*.*$)"      match = Regex.Match(StrXyz.Trim.ToString.ToUpper, strPattern)
                        If match.Success Then
                            e.Valid = False
                            StrFlag = False
                        Else
                            flag = True
                        End If

Comment: The A in "test XYZA test" must be A or any alphabet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59253/discussion-between-pradeep-kumar-and-nirav-vasoya).

Comment: Yes, In this case If XYZ is not in string then we have to give the error.  Valid Case I give you above, But invalid case like(For Ex.1)test XYZAB test 2) XYZ12 test 3) test XYZ12AB 4) XYZ123)